# Flutter conditional animation

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I have a `Stack` of 5 `Text` as children. Each child is wrapped with a `FadeTransition` object. Outside the Stack I have 5 `RaisedButton` that maps to one `Text` each. By default, `Text` 1 has opacity of `1` and the rest has `0` opacity. When a button is clicked, the opacity of the text that it maps become `1` and the rest become `0`. 
To do that I created 5 different `AnimationController` and hardcoded a very long logic. **I am not sure that this is the correct way to do that in Flutter. 
I believe there must be some easier way.** 
 Moreover, this is a simplified example. The issue in my real application has even complex conditions. (For example, show only Text 2 and Text 3 when Button 5 is clicked and the boolean `hasViewedText1` is true  .)

[image]

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() {
    return _State();
  }
}

class _State extends State<Test> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController1;
  AnimationController _animationController2;
  AnimationController _animationController3;
  AnimationController _animationController4;
  AnimationController _animationController5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController1 = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _animationController2 = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _animationController3 = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _animationController4 = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _animationController5 = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _everyThingBackward();
    _animationController1.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        elevation: 0.5,
        title: new Text(
          "Testing views",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
        ),
      ),
//      body: _buildBodyAnimationTest(),
//      body:  _buildTuto(),
//      body: _builtLayoutBuilder(),
      body: _builtLayoutConditionalAnimation(),
    );
  }


  Widget _builtLayoutConditionalAnimation() {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button 1"), onPressed: () {
              _everyThingBackward();
              _animationController1.forward();
            }),
            new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button 2"), onPressed: () {
              _everyThingBackward();
              _animationController2.forward();
            }),
            new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button 3"), onPressed: () {
              _everyThingBackward();
              _animationController3.forward();
            }),
            new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button 4"), onPressed: () {
              _everyThingBackward();
              _animationController4.forward();
            }),
            new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button 5"), onPressed: () {
              _everyThingBackward();
              _animationController5.forward();
            }),
          ],
        ),
        new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            FadeTransition(opacity: _animationController1,child: new Text('Text 1 is clicked')),
            FadeTransition(opacity: _animationController2,child: new Text('Text 2 is clicked')),
            FadeTransition(opacity: _animationController3,child: new Text('Text 3 is clicked')),
            FadeTransition(opacity: _animationController4,child: new Text('Text 4 is clicked')),
            FadeTransition(opacity: _animationController5,child: new Text('Text 5 is clicked')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _everyThingBackward() {
    _animationController1.reverse();
    _animationController2.reverse();
    _animationController3.reverse();
    _animationController4.reverse();
    _animationController5.reverse();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can me made a lot simpler by using the `AnimatedSwitcher` widget, [link to docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html).

Here is a full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(child: Center(child: Test())),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Widget _child = Text(
    "No Button Tapped!",
    key: UniqueKey(),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Button 1"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _child = Text(
                "Button 1 Tapped!",
                key: UniqueKey(),
              );
            });
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Button 2"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _child = Text(
                "Button 2 Tapped!",
                key: UniqueKey(),
              );
            });
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Button 3"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _child = Text(
                "Button 3 Tapped!",
                key: UniqueKey(),
              );
            });
          },
        ),
        AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          child: _child,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This medium article might be useful too: https://medium.com/flutter-community/what-do-you-know-about-aniamtedswitcher-53cc3a4bebb8